# A inclusion of sobolev space $W^{2,p}$ in a Holder space

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes, holder-spaces, fractional-sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{N}$ be a bounded smooth domain and $L$ a uniformly elliptic operator given by
$$
Lu = -div(A(x) \nabla u) + \langle b(x), \nabla u\rangle + c(x) u,
$$
where $b = (b_{1}, ..., b_{N})$, $c, b_{i} \in L^{\infty}(\Omega)$ and $A(x) = (a_{ij}(x))_{ij}$ is a symmetric matrice with $a_{ij} \in C^{1}(\overline{\Omega})$. Given $f \in L^{2}(\Omega)$, I know that, for $f \in L^{2}(\Omega)$ there's a constant $M_{0} > 0$ for which the equation
$$
\begin{cases}
      (L+ M)u = f, \Omega \\
        \hspace{16mm} u = 0, \partial \Omega,
\end{cases}
$$
has a unique weak solution for every $M \geq M_{0}$. Fixed $M \geq M_{0}$ and given $f \in L^{2}(\Omega)$, let $u_{f}$ the weak solution of the obove system. Define the map $T_{M} : L^{2}(\Omega) \rightarrow H^{1}_0(\Omega)$ by $T_{M}(f) = u_{f}$. I want to prove that
$$
T_{M}(f)  \in C^{1}_0(\overline{\Omega}), \quad \forall f \in C^{1}_0(\overline{\Omega}).
$$

**What I have tried**: As any function in $C^{1}_0(\overline{\Omega})$ is in $L^{p}(\Omega)$, for all $p \in [1,\infty]$, I know from elliptic $L^{p}$ regularity that the weak solution $u_f$ is in $W^{2,p}(\Omega)$, for all $p > 1$ in the case that $f \in C^{1}_0(\Omega)$. In other words, $$
T_{M}(f) \in W^{2,p}(\Omega), \forall f \in C^{1}_0(\overline{\Omega})\text{ and } \forall p > 1.
$$
Taking $p$ bigger enough such that $2 > N/p$ and $[N/p] = 0$ (the integer part of N/p), we know that
$$
W^{2,p}(\Omega) \hookrightarrow C^{1, (1 - N/p)}(\overline{\Omega}).
$$
That's what I could thought, I don't know if this is the best way to go. I really thank any help or reference.

Comment: So, you have already proved the desired result?

Comment: No, I haven't .

Comment: This looks like a valid attempt. Where do you see difficulties? If it is the best way to go depends on what you want to achieve...

Comment: I have no idea how to conclude what I want.